# perl regular expression to substitute

Tags: html, perl, pattern-matching

In a html file, I wish to add a link to the numbers within the [ ] in these patterns: [1] or [1-2] or [1,3,6] or [1,3,4-6, 9]. I know how to match the simple ones such as the first one:

```
$html =~ s`\[\d+\]`\[<a href="#$1"><$1>\]`g;
```

How about the rest of the patterns?

also, for this pattern: [1], I want to just look for a number which is between a [ and ], ignoring anything else in the pattern match and substitution because in my html code, the numbers in the [] could have different html code associated with them.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to show exactly what you want to change them into. Given `[1,3,4-6,9]`, what do you want it to become?

Comment: Sorry, I did not make my purpose clear. The numbers in the [ ] are citations in an article and need to be linked to the actual references at the end of the article (like what you see in Wikipedia articles). The numbers in the original html file are not linked. I just want the numbers to have links without changing the pattern, for example 4-6 in [1,3,4-6,9] will be <a href=#4>4</a>-<a href=#6>6</a>

Comment: is your question answered?

Comment: I got it to work using this code:  if ($html =~ m/\[/g){
     $html =~ s`\G(.*?)(\d+)(?=[,|\-|\s|\d]*\])`$1<a href="#$2">$2</a>`g;  
  }

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED

Algorithm:

```
use Data::Dumper;

# input
my $html = "[1],[1-2],[1,3,6],[1,3,4-6],[5]";

# result array
my @result;

# recursive way to generate html link tag
sub asHtmlLink($) {
    return "<a href=\"\#$_[0]\">$_[0]</a>";
}

# seperate by ,
foreach (split(',',$html)) {

    # match pattern
    m/(\d+)(\-)?(\d+)?/g;

    # if there is a digit after a minus
    if (defined $3) { 
        push(@result,asHtmlLink($1).$2.asHtmlLink($3));
    } else {
        push(@result,asHtmlLink($1));
    }
}

# dump
print Dumper @result;
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = '<a href="#1">1</a>';
$VAR2 = '<a href="#1">1</a>-<a href="#2">2</a>';
$VAR3 = '<a href="#1">1</a>';
$VAR4 = '<a href="#3">3</a>';
$VAR5 = '<a href="#6">6</a>';
$VAR6 = '<a href="#1">1</a>';
$VAR7 = '<a href="#3">3</a>';
$VAR8 = '<a href="#4">4</a>-<a href="#6">6</a>';
$VAR9 = '<a href="#5">5</a>';
```

Regex Link: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lV8wY0)

Comment: Maybe that is not what I wanted. the text should remain the same after inserting a url for each number. for example, the order of numbers, commas, hypens should remain unchanged in [1,3,4-6, 9].

Comment: +1, but you should use `\d` instead of `\d{1}`, and maybe `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use Carp::Assert 'assert';

sub replace {
  my $html = shift;

  # first expand subexpressions of the for "n-m"; (will fail if
  # n > m !)
  1 while $html =~ s{
                     (\[\s*(?:\s*\d\s*,\s*)*)     # prefix (1)
                     (\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)            # target (2, 3)
                     (?=[^\]]*\])                 # suffix (lookahead)
                    }
                    {assert($2 <= $3),
                     $1 . join(", ", $2..$3)}ex;

  # now replace individual integers with hyperlinks
  1 while $html =~ s{
                     (\[\s*(?:\s*\d+\s*,\s*)*)    # prefix (1)
                     (\d+)                        # target (2)
                     (?=[^\]]*\])                 # suffix (lookahead)
                    }
                    {$1\n<a href="#$2">$2</a>}x;  # \n added to make
                                                  # output easier to
                                                  # to read; it's safe
                                                  # to omit it


  return $html;
}
```

Some informal tests:

```
for my $h ( '[1, 3-7,  10-11 ]',
            '[  0]',
            '[1  ]',
            '[ ]',
            '[ 9-19]',
            '[9-9]',
            '[19-9]',
            '[19-z]'
          ) {
  my $r = eval { replace($h); };
  if ( $@ ) {
    $r = $@;
  }
  printf "%s\n%s\n\n", $h, $r;
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3-7,  10-11 ]
[
<a href="#1">1</a>,
<a href="#3">3</a>,
<a href="#4">4</a>,
<a href="#5">5</a>,
<a href="#6">6</a>,
<a href="#7">7</a>,
<a href="#10">10</a>,
<a href="#11">11</a> ]

[  0]
[
<a href="#0">0</a>]

[1  ]
[
<a href="#1">1</a>  ]

[ ]
[ ]

[ 9-19]
[
<a href="#9">9</a>,
<a href="#10">10</a>,
<a href="#11">11</a>,
<a href="#12">12</a>,
<a href="#13">13</a>,
<a href="#14">14</a>,
<a href="#15">15</a>,
<a href="#16">16</a>,
<a href="#17">17</a>,
<a href="#18">18</a>,
<a href="#19">19</a>]

[9-9]
[
<a href="#9">9</a>]
```

Comment: well.. this is real power.. but i do not now what you exactly do ;) can you provide your input?

Comment: @AlexTape: the input consists of the cases `'[1, 3-7,  10-11 ]', ..., '[19-z]'` processed in the `for my $h (...)` loop (right after the sentence "Some informal tests:").

Comment: @kjo  there is no need to expand the numbers flanking a hyphen. for a input like [9-19], the output should be [<a href=#9>9</a>-<a href=#19>19</a>].

Comment: @bigbyte: I did not code it that way because such an output makes no semantic sense: `9-19` means "references 9 through 19", which should correspond to a total of 11 hyperlinks, not 2.  Next time, include in your question the specific output you want for given input, rather than have those who answer guess.